# way too slow in retrieving results in parallel python (pp)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, parallel-python

I used parallel python (pp) package in order to perform a serial parallel processing over my 4-core laptop. 
Here is a quick summary of the scripts used to do the job. After initializing the parallel python object, I split up my task over 4 jobs and retrieved them to a list.

```
import pp
ppservers = ()
job_server = pp.Server(ppservers = ppservers)

start = 1
end = 1000
parts = 4
step = (end-start)/parts + 1

jobs=[]
for i in xrange(parts):
   starti = pp_start + i * step - 1
   endi = min(pp_start + (i+1)*step - 1,pp_end)
jobs.append(job_server.submit(functionName,(arg1,arg2)))

results=[job() for job in jobs]
```

What I noticed was that the for-loop performance was fairly fast (within a few seconds) but the retrieving process (results = [job() for job in jobs]) took way too long (approximately 10 minutes).

Could someone explain why this is and recommend a way to get around this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are spawning 1000 processes, so that means 1000 python instances.  For a small job like yours, it's going to slow you down by quite a lot.  You don't want `pp` for this.  Worse still, if your `ppservers` are over the network (instead of local processes), then you not only have the overhead of making a socket connection, but you also have the overhead of sending code across the network to spawn a python instance on another computer(s).  If you don't want to use the socket and internet connection, you can force `pp` to only work locally by setting `ppservers=()`, (which it seems that you are already doing).  `pp` also has to serialize your code, and send it across processes, and then reconstitute the code object in the other process -- which can also slow things down.  I wouldn't expect 10 minutes, unless you are going across sockets, or that you are pegging your memory with the spawned python instances.

I'd recommend using threads instead of `pp` in this case, -- so the `multiprocessing` library, since your function seems like it might be small.

IF you want a library that provides a nice abstraction to `pp` and `multiprocessing` so you can pick and choose which to deploy for a particular job without otherwise changing your code, you can try `pathos`.  `pathos` also provides defaults and tweaks for `pp` that help speed it up.  Then you can test out which way it's the fastest to run your function, and go with that.

```
>>> import pathos.pp as pp
>>> import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
>>>    
>>> def squared(x):
...   return x**2
... 
>>> pppool = pp.ParallelPythonPool()
>>> mppool = mp.ProcessingPool()
>>> 
>>> res = pppool.amap(squared, xrange(1000))
>>> sqd = mppool.map(squared, xrange(1000))
>>> sqd[:10], sqd[-10:]
([0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], [980100, 982081, 984064, 986049, 988036, 990025, 992016, 994009, 996004, 998001])
>>> 
>>> sq = res.get()
>>> sq[:10], sq[-10:]
([0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], [980100, 982081, 984064, 986049, 988036, 990025, 992016, 994009, 996004, 998001])
>>> 
>>> thpool = mp.ThreadingPool()
>>> s = thpool.imap(squared, xrange(1000))
>>> s = list(s)
>>> s[:10], s[-10:]
([0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81], [980100, 982081, 984064, 986049, 988036, 990025, 992016, 994009, 996004, 998001])
```

Above, I'm doing `multiprocessing` with a blocking map, while doing `pp` with a asynchronous (nonblocking) map.  Then afterward, I do an iterator map with threads (leveraging `multiprocessing`).  BTW, `pathos` also provides connectivity to `MPI` and cluster schedulers as well (not shown above).

Get `pathos` here: https://github.com/uqfoundation

Comment: Thanks Mike for making the difference between pp and multiprocessing clear. I will do some testing how my code evolves in both approaches.